# breaking from an infinite while loop , why is this code not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop

I am trying to make the while loop break when the user inputs 5, but why is this code not working:

```
var arr = [];
while(!arr.includes(5)){
    arr.push(prompt("Enter a Number"));

}
alert("NUmber is here");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`prompt` will always return a *string*, not a number. Change to:

```
while(!arr.includes('5')){
```

```js
var arr = [];
while(!arr.includes('5')){
    arr.push(prompt("Enter a Number"));

}
alert("NUmber is here");
```

Answer (score 0):

The value returned from prompt is a string so convert it to a number and then make a check

```
var arr = [];
while(!arr.includes(5)){
    arr.push(parseInt(prompt("Enter a Number")));

}
alert("NUmber is here");
```

Comment: Watch out for this one - when someone enters into the prompt that is not a number, the results might be different than you expect.

Answer (score 0):

the `includes` method uses strict equality (`===`)  to check if a specific value is in the array.  `prompt` will always return a string, not a number, therefore the integer 5 will never be in the array. However, the string "5" will be.

When you change your code to `while(!arr.includes('5')){` (as CertainPerformance points out, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [];
while(!arr.includes(5)){
  var num = parseInt(prompt("Enter a Number"));
  arr.push(num);
}
alert("NUmber is here");
```

Or you can use :

```
var arr = [];
while(!arr.includes('5')){
  arr.push(prompt("Enter a Number"));
}
alert("NUmber is here");
```

Because includes check equality strictly.